# Visual Studio Breaks on Exceptions for Async Calls Instead of Being Caught in Catch()

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have the following code that is trying to catch the exception caused by a disconnect:

```
try
{
    DataReaderLoadOperation op = dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)readBuffer.MaxLength());
    await op;  //  <-- Debugger show COMException here
    ReceiveCallback(op, op.Status);
}
catch (COMException e)
{
    Logger.Info("{0} disconnected. (Waiting)", this);
    Logger.Debug("{0} exception = {1}", this, e);
    OnDisconnected();
}
```

Why does my code not catch it? Here is the dump of the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred   
  HResult=-2147014842   
  Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072746)   
  Source=mscorlib   
  ErrorCode=-2147014842   
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Crystal.IO.Network.SocketClient.<WaitForIncoming>d__4.MoveNext() in d:\Crystal\library\IO\Network\SocketClient.cs:line 479   
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you sure your debugger is not set to break on first chance exceptions?

Comment: I took a look at my exception settings, and it was set to break on all exceptions. I fixed that, and now it seems to work correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. For future references, I moved my comment to answer below. Please mark it as an answer if it helped fix your issues. Thanks :)

Comment: To clarify what this question is about, the OP opened Debug > Exceptions... in Visual Studio and checked the "Thrown" checkbox for CLR Exceptions, then sometime later tried to catch an async Exception and found that Visual Studio was breaking on the Exception, rather than letting it flow to the catch clause. A default install of Visual Studio won't exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your debugger settings to not break on first chance exceptions.

Comment: @Carlo check this link out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/19/440632.aspx